# How to test same user is available in next half hour in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame like below.

```
df:
x1       x2     x3       X4
user1  13:00    12:30    13:30
user2  13:30    13:00    14:00
user3  15:00    14:30    15:30
user1  13:10    12:40    13:40
```

Here X1 is the user, X2 is the actual time, X3 is the less than half hour time than actual time. X4 is the next half an hour time than actual.

Here, we have user1 repeated next half an hour also i have to look based on X3 time column. The X3 time 12:40(i.e, 12:30 < 13:00 < 13:30).So, User1 is available to next an hour also.

I have to test like above.Please,Suggest me ideas.

```
Expected Output:
X1           X2
user1       1
user2       0
user3       0

X5 is the new column that will tell user available next half an hour time or not. 1 means available, 0 means not available.
```

Comment: Can you explain what x2 and x3 mean, and give your desired output from the sample dataset?

Comment: X2 and X3 are time.

Comment: @iod,I have edited my question, Please, see once.

Comment: I don't understand why `user1` and `user3` are available (X5 = 1 in your expected output), but `user2` is not (X5 = 0). They look like they should all be the same. Can you explain why?

Comment: @GregorThomas, Edited my question. I just want to know if the same user available between 12:30 < 13:00 < 13:30 .

Comment: Maybe you could edit your example so it shows at least one 1 in the result? I think I understand, but I'd like to be sure...

Comment: @GregorThomas, I have edited question, Please,see once.

Comment: maybe it is just me, but it s very difficult to understand the logic behind this. Do all users show up multiple times in the data? For each user you have a given time (+ - 30 min), and an additional observation with "actual" time, and you want to know if it is in the interval? If yes, it would make sense to organize the data in wide form

Comment: @desval,Yes, all users have multiple times in the data. I can not put the whole data here that is why I have created  sample data which is look like actual data

Comment: Why does `user1` have 2 rows in the sample input, but only one row in the sample output? What is the logic for removing rows? (Since `user2` and `user3` show up in the sample output, I would expect `user1` to be there twice, as in the input.)

Comment: Also, I want to be clear, that, for the definition of `x5`, only `x1` and `x2` matter, right?

Comment: @GregorThomas, Sorry, there is no need to be time columns in the output. Just User with available or not column will be useful. No, for x5 it needs to be x1,x2 and x3 columns like above.

Comment: @GregorThomas, user may start at any point of time

Comment: So the result is 1 row per user, indicating whether they have two `x2` values within 30 minutes of each other?

Comment: I'm now more confused by *"for x5 it needs to be x1,x2 and x3 columns like above"*. You've deleted `x5` and renamed it `X2`, and I don't see what `x3` has to do with the definition of `X2`. Do you care about `x2` values within 30 minutes of each other, or is this something variable that we need to check `x3` to find out?

Comment: @GregorThomas, for output what you have said is right. It depends on x1 and x2 column  . That x5 is the type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `chron::times` to work with the times and `dplyr` for grouped operations.

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(x2 = times(paste0(x2, ":00"))) %>%
  select(x1, x2) %>%
  left_join(., ., by = "x1") %>%
  group_by(x1) %>%
  summarize(result = as.integer(any(
    x2.y - x2.x > times("00:00:00") &
      x2.y - x2.x <= times("00:30:00")
  )))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   x1    result
#   <fct>  <int>
# 1 user1      1
# 2 user2      0
# 3 user3      0
```

Using this sample data:

```
df = read.table(
text = "x1       x2     x3       X4
user1  13:00    12:30    13:30
user2  13:30    13:00    14:00
user3  15:00    14:30    15:30
user1  13:10    12:40    13:40", header = T)
```

Comment: Why you joined the tables before grouping?

Comment: Because it's the joined table that I want to group. If you run through line by line, it should make sense.